# Prometheus file based service discovery

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, service-discovery, prometheus-operator

I tried file based service discovery ,But everytime when I change the configmap(which contains static target), I am deleting prometheus pod manually to get config changes. Is there any way that prometheus can get config changes automatically without deleting the prometheus pod? any help on this issue?

I am installing prometheus-operator using helm chart
target.json file

````
[
  {
    "labels": {
      "app": "web",
      "env": "dev"
    },
    "targets": [
      "web.dev.svc.cluster.local"
   ]
  }
]```

command I used to create configmap

kubectl create cm static-config --from-file=target.json -n monitoring

prometheus-operator.yaml

```volumes:
- name: config-volume
  configMap:
    name: static-config

volumeMounts:
- name: config-volume
  mountPath: /etc/prometheus/config


additionalScrapeConfigs:
- job_name: 'file-based-targets'
  file_sd_configs:
  - files:
    - '/etc/prometheus/config/target.json'```
````

Answer (score 1):

Prometheus reloads file_sd_configs automatically using file watches according to the documentation:

> It reads a set of files containing a list of zero or more <static_config>s. Changes to all defined files are detected via disk watches and applied immediately. Files may be provided in YAML or JSON format. Only changes resulting in well-formed target groups are applied.

https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#file_sd_config

If you need to add more target files you can use a wildcard for the files, for example:

```yaml
scrape_configs:
- job_name: 'file-based-targets'
  file_sd_configs:
  - files:
    - '/etc/prometheus/targets/*.json'
```

If you still need reloading from configmaps you can add another container to the Prometheus CRD and use either the built-in `prometheus-operator/prometheus-config-reloader` (this is how the Prometheus configuration and rules are reloaded) or one of the following:

- https://github.com/kiwigrid/k8s-sidecar
- https://github.com/jimmidyson/configmap-reload
- https://github.com/stakater/Reloader